# Spring Application Context add bean to retrieve password

Tags: spring, cyber-ark

I have a Spring Context with a bean id called batchdatasource that refer to class `DriverManagerDataSource` and with four properties `driverClassName`, `url`, `username` and `password`.

I get the value for placeholder from an external file called `database.properties`.
The placeholder are: `jdbc.driverClassName`, `jdbc.url`, `jdbc.username` and `jdbc.password`

The value of the password is composed of a string that contains a series of key/value parameter, for example, **"APP_ID:AIM_T26;SAFE:AIM_T26_DEV"**.
How can I insert a bean that elaborates this password composed by parameters and return the password of type `String` in the Spring context?
I need to elaborate the password with a cyberark library. In fact in the `database.properties` file there isn't the password but a string to pass to cyberark library to get the password.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The easiest would be to write a `BeanPostProcessor` which would do this (after the properties have been set on the datasource). On a different note, you probably shouldn't be using the `DriverManagerDatasource` but a proper connection pool instead.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum I extended Spring DriverManagerDatasource in order to override getPassword method.

Comment: Which, as I stated, you shouldn't be using in the first place. `DriverManagerDataSource` is a bad choice for a production ready datasource. It is usable for demos and tests but please don't use it in production as it is slow and potentially leads to issues on the DB side (lots of connections). You should be using a proper datasource instead.